# Equals method implemented in the class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this a proper way to implement an equality check?  In `Equals` method, I am relying on    `bad_cast` exception to know if the objects are of the same class or not.

Is there any other way to implement `Equals()` in C++?

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = 0;
    bool operator==(const Shape& s) 
    {
        return Equals(s);
    }

    virtual bool Equals(const Shape& s) = 0;        
};



class Circle : public Shape
{


    bool Equals(const Shape& c) override
    {
        try
        {
            const Circle& other = dynamic_cast<const Circle&>(c);
                      // condition to check equality.
        }
        catch(std::bad_cast&)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
};

class Square : public Shape   
{
    bool Equals(const Shape& s)  override
    {       
        try
        {
            const Square& other = dynamic_cast<const Square&>(s);
                      // condition to check equality.
        }
        catch(std::bad_cast&)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            throw;
        }       
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Shape> ShapePtr;
typedef std::vector<ShapePtr> Shapes;

Shapes LoadShapes()
{
    Shapes shapes;
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(42));
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(52));
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(62));
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Square>(10));
    return shapes;
}

int main()
{
    auto circle = std::make_shared<Circle>(42);
    auto shapes = LoadShapes();
    for ( auto& shape : shapes)
    {
        if ( *shape == *circle)
        {
            std::cout << *shape << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Made the `operator==` as non-virtual method.

Comment: Why did you make operator== as non-virtual method?

Comment: Since I had the Equals() method, there was no need for operator== to be virtual. Isn't it ? But then, we don't need the Equals() method and we could just override the operator== by making the operator== in base class pure virtual there by forcing the implementation in derived classes.

Comment: looks like redundant to me. what benefits are you going to get from extra equals method?

Comment: I agree. Equals() method does not bring any extra benifit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` on *pointers* will never throw. Instead, it will return `0`.

Furthermore, why do you actually have the `Equals` function? You can make `operator ==` virtual directly. This leaves us with:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
    bool operator ==(const Shape& c) override
    {
        auto other = dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&c);
        return other != 0 and /* check equality */;
    }
};
```

Apart from that, the code `catch (...) { throw; }` never makes sense. If you’re going to rethrow the exception without any action anyway, why catch it in the first place?

As per the comments, the declaration of `other` can be abbreviated. This is recommended in C++11, especially since the exact type of the variable is already explicitly mentioned in the initialiser expression.

Comment: dynamic_cast will throw a bad_cast in case of reference type.

Comment: @innochenti Erm … yes. Of course.

Comment: now ok. :) also, better auto other = dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&c); 'cause there is type in dynamic_cast

Comment: @innochenti Yes, I agree. I didn’t see the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to bump this one year old question, but there is something inherently wrong in your equality check **if you ever extend to more than one level of inheritance**.

Consider a class `Foo` deriving from `Circle`, assuming the same implementation (with changed types of course).

```
Foo foo;
Circle circle;
Shape & shapeFoo = foo;
Shape & shapeCircle = circle;

// these two should behave the same, but they don't:
std::cout << (shapeFoo == shapeCircle) << std::endl;
std::cout << (shapeCircle == shapeFoo) << std::endl;
```

Why does this fail?

`shapeFoo == shapeCircle` will call `shapeFoo.Equals(shapeCircle)` which will be dispatched on the implementation of `Equals` in class `Foo`. There the `dynamic_cast<Foo const *>` will fail, correctly returning `false`.

However `shapeCircle == shapeFoo` will call `shapeCircle.Equals(shapeFoo)` which will be dispatched on the implementation of `Equals` in **class `Circle`**. There the `dynamic_cast<Circle *>` will succeed (as Foo is a descendant of Circle). Then the method will compare only the attributes of `Circle`, probably returning true.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Circle : public Shape
{


    bool Equals(const Shape& c) override
```

Why not a virtual "operator =="?

```
    {
        try
        {
            const Circle& other = dynamic_cast<const Circle&>(c);
```

Switching to pointer based `dynamic_cast` and checking for `NULL` might be better. Throwing and catching the exception is probably slightly more expensive than checking for null in and if. Its also not a particulairly common c++ idiom to catch exceptions as a logic decision like this.

```
                      // condition to check equality.
        }
        catch(std::bad_cast&)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Why? If you don't want to do anything with other exceptions, don't catch them.

```
    }
};
```

Comment: do you mean that "other" exceptions should be caught outside equals function?

Comment: Please do not spread Urban legends (or provide a reference that is not 20 years old). Exceptions are not expensive in modern implementations. This may have been a problem with the initial implementation of exceptions and caused a lot of bad rep to the use of exceptions but modern implementations are highly efficient. In the above code it is not the cost of the exception that worries me but the cost of the dynamic_cast.

Comment: @LokiAstari, my wording came out stronger then I intended. My understanding is that throwing exceptions is more expensive then ordinary execution. Its not huge, but the performance difference is still there.

Comment: I would argue with "throwing exceptions is more expensive". If you handle exceptions; then If you take into account the extra code you have to manually insert to achieve the same affect as the exception handling code I doubt that exceptions are any more expensive than the manual code. If you don't handle the exception then sure it is cheaper. But it is a couple of years since I did this test and I am unsure how the exception mechanism has changed in the interim.

Comment: @LokiAstari, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018800/performance-of-c0x-exceptions. Of course this comes down to how the compiler/runtime implement exceptions, and will vary from case to case.